# Converting preorder general tree to post in Racket

Tags: recursion, tree, scheme, racket, tree-traversal

I'm new to Racket and I've read through many webpages of information but I am having trouble with implementing a general tree as a list of list of numbers.
If I am taking in the following pre-order tree input from stdin:

```
1 3
2 2
5 0
6 0
3 1
7 0
4 4
8 0
9 0
10 0
11 1
12 0
```

where the *first number represents the value of the node* and *the second value represents the number of children the node has*.
I would be trying to produce my expected result before converting it into post-order as:

```
'(1 (2 (5 6)) (3 ( 7)) (4 (8 9 10 11 (12))))
```

So far I have the following:

```
(define recurse 0)

(define (getTreeInfo)
  (local ((define line (read-line)))
    (if (eof-object? line)
        empty
        (if (= recurse 1)
            (makeTree (string->number(first (string-split line))) (- (string->number(second (string-split line))) 1))
            (makeTree (string->number(first (string-split line))) (string->number(second (string-split line))))))))

(define (makeTree value numChildren)
  (cond
    [(= numChildren 0) (begin (set! recurse 0)
                              (printf "Recurse: ~a\n" recurse)
                              (cons )]
    [else (begin (set! recurse 1)
                 (printf "Recurse: ~a\n" recurse)
                 (cons value (getTreeInfo)))]))
```

The code isn't complete nor correct, but it's a starting point of my thought process.
Any ideas how to approach this traversal? I'm feeling like mutual recursion is needed here.

Answer (score 1):

I can't quite make sense of the expected result. The children look to be mostly contained within sublists except the children of node `1` are not, and since `11` is a subtree, I think it should be `(11 (12))`. So, in my head a possible result could look like `'(1 ((2 (5 6)) (3 (7)) (4 (8 9 10 (11 (12))))))`, where the children of each node are in their own list.

A version of the `getTreeInfo` function could take another argument that keeps track of how many more children the current node expects, decrementing it with each recursive step.  I haven't used scheme much, so I'm not sure this is idiomatic, but here is an example.

```
;; IN is input stream, N is number of children remaining for current node
(define (getTreeInfo in n)
  (if (zero? n) null                      ; no more children, return nil
      (let ([line (map string->number (string-split (read-line)))])
        (cond
         [(zero? (cadr line)) (list (car line))] ; node has no children
         [else
          (let ([children '()])
            (for ([_ (in-range (cadr line))])
              (set! children (append children (getTreeInfo in 1))))
            (cons (list (car line) children) (getTreeInfo in (sub1 n))))]))))

;; take input from stdin and start N at 1
(car (getTreeInfo (current-input-port) 1))
```

From command line,

```
$ racket reorder.rkt < tree.txt
'(1 ((2 (5 6)) (3 (7)) (4 (8 9 10 (11 (12))))))
```